# Logging in as root but can't run `meteor` or `meteor update` command?

Tags: meteor, digital-ocean

When I run `meteor`, it just says `killed`.

Did Digital Ocean install a new firewall or block some ports recently? I'm pretty sure these used to work. `ping www.google.com` seems to work fine

Comment: What do you mean by 'can't run' ? Do you get any errors? Firewalls shouldn't affect whether you can run the command. I'm using Meteor on two digital ocean servers and I have no problems. Also you probably shouldn't be running meteor as root.

Comment: When I run `meteor`, it just says `killed`. Edited the question. If that is the expected response, then I'll settle. However, recently I have not deployed successfully to DO and was wondering if they changed any of their settings without me knowing. Therefore I was just testing the `meteor` command.

Comment: Which droplet image are you using?

Comment: Sorry for my late comment, I was just using the standard Ubuntu Droplet